# Issues with android market posting

Tags: android

I posted my app in market but I cannot see that when I search by app name i.e. "NIM TEST".
Whereas when i search by package, it workd fine. 
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nimtest

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: I would guess the app name has yet to be indexed for search. I would give it a couple hours.

Comment: Might just need time to propegate into the search results

Comment: This does not look like programming question for me, maybe better migrate it to some other stackexchange site?

Comment: I think it is "related to software development in some way" as this question is about the deployment stage of a software development project.

Answer (score 1):

I Posted my app to the market 3 weeks ago.  It took about three hours before it appeared in the search results. It was slightly quicker at appearing by package name and in the market app. I never saw it appear on the "just In" list.

If you google your apps name you should see it start appearing on sites like AppBrain

Answer (score 0):

Like others have already said it takes a couple of hours for the app name to be indexed and appear in search results. It may also sound like a stupid question but, if your searching through the mobile Market Place, does the phone your searching on meet the minimum API level? A few people I know couldn't (for good reason) find my app because their devices were below the minimum specified API level.

I would suggest waiting for a while and also checking it on a computer if you haven't already.

However I wouldn't recommend publishing applications like the 'nimtest' one you have, JUST for testing. This clogs up the market with waste and I'm pretty sure this would not satisfy the basic quality requirement you have to agree to when publishing :P